Table Query From MySql 8.4 Command Line Client Returns "Empty Set" While Perl script query returns the called item
Using Mysql 8.4
mysql> SELECT * FROM jobs;
Empty set (0.00 Sec)

After connecting to the database this Perl script returns a file "supposedly posted to the table 'jobs' in jobs_db
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT EmployerID,EmployerName,Title,City,StateProvince,Description,Function,Sector,Country,Posted FROM jobs WHERE JobID = ?");
$sth->execute ($JobID );

How can this be? Where is the file if not in the jobs table?

Are there two DATABASEs, each with a TABLE named jobs?  And one is empty?
